# Javascript scope with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, scope

I have following code:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9F6TQ/)

```
<a id="test">Click me</a>
<a id="field2" style="border: 1px solid green;">0</a>


var i = 0;
$('a#test').click(function() {
     i += 1;
     var a = i;

     $('a#test').popover({
         trigger: 'manual',
         placement: 'right',
         content: function() {
            var message = "Count is" + a;
              return message;
         }
    });
    $('a#test').popover("show");
    $('a#field2').html(a);
});
```

When clicking on Click Me Only one value gets incremented, but if we change message line to:

```
var message = "Count is" + i;
```

Both values gets incremented.

Why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The popover construction happens only once, during the first click event, because you cannot reconstruct a popover without destroying the old one.

So in your case :

- `"Count is " + a`, you construct the popover callback from the `a` variable with the current value of a. Because you are 'recreating' `a` at each click, the reference used will be the one of the first `a` variable created (during the first click). This reference will be lose once you'll be out the event function, so you won't be able to update it and only the first value will be used in the callback.
- `"Count is " + i`, you construct the popover callback using the global variable `i` which will be available wherever and whenever you want, so you can modify it.

Obviously the `#field2`  will show the current value because you're using the current `a` variable and not the old one from the first click.

To understand a bit more :

1. First click : i = 1, a = 1. You're sending `a`, which could be seen as `a1` (first a) to the callback function). Then you go out the event function, so the `a` variable is destroyed BUT 'its memory' (what it was pointing in fact, everything is reference in javascript), so in memory you still have something like `a0 -> 1` which is used in the callback.
2. Second click : i = 2, a = 2. You're NOT sending `a` to the popover constructor because you've already created the popover, so it is still `a0` which is used in the callback function. Then you go out the event function, and now the `a` variable is pointing to its value.
3. Third click : Same as second, and etc.

Comment: You can put a console.log(i, a) inside content function and see that it gets called several times

Comment: @user2846569 I'm not talking about the callback function but about the popover constructor. Obviously the callback function is called at each click (because popover is trigger at each click), but without changing the `a` reference.

Answer (score 1):

The `popover()` call within the click event is not recreating the popover on each click. It is only created on the first click, any further recreate attempts are ignored.

Both are incremented when you use `i` in the `content` function because `i` is delcared as a global, and it is being modified on each click. The `content` function is not taking a snapshot of `i`, it is referencing the updated variable every time `content` is called.

When you change to use `a` in the `content` function, it doesn't get incremented because `content` is only seeing the first time `a` is declared due to `a` being a local variable (and because `content` is only created once).

This can be tested by destroying the popover on each click, which now means the popover is recreated on each click, which results in both being incremented:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ES8rC/)

Note: the demo uses the latest Bootstrap because 2.02 in your fiddle doesn't support the destroy method.

Answer (score 0):

after declaring the `var a` outside the `click function()` your problem is solved.I am not sure why this is happening but it seems that the `a` inside the `content function` has a different value then `a` outside the `content function` after doing the above mentioned changes you get your results.Hope it helps.Updated fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9F6TQ/4/)